# How to detect the Grid is filtered

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, filter, order-grid

I want to get increment id whenever `filter is applied` to the sales order grid.And When filter is cleared i need to revert the changes.

This is what i have done  so far:

```
$collection = $this->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    if (check whether filter is applied) {
        echo $item->getData('increment_id');
    }
}
```

How do i detect whether the filter is applied or not??

Comment: In which file you are using above code? php, phtml?

Comment: @John  i'm using it in grid.phtml

Comment: Can you please add full path of your file?

Comment: app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$this->getParam($this->getVarNameFilter(), null);` to check whether filter is applied or not to the collection.

So try below code.

```
$collection = $this->getCollection();
$filter     = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameFilter(), null);
foreach ($collection as $item) {

    //allows only when filter is applied
    if ($filter) {
        echo $item->getData('increment_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.

```
$filter = $this->getRequest()->getParam('filter');
$collection = $this->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    if ($filter) {
        echo $item->getData('increment_id');
    }
}
```